# Suppress error message in JUnit for a forced/known error in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

So, I'm just making some sample test cases in JUnit using eclipse. One of my examples is to create a simple add(int, int) method and test that a String can't be one of the params. `assertFalse(myclass.add("a",5));` My issue is that Eclipse shows that error icon next to the number line and underlines the add method w/ the red error line. It also ask's if I want to proceed when I hit compile. Is there a way suppress this warning since I am forcing it to happen, or is this a bad testing practice? I can always hit ignore for compilation but the red x still remains which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You donot need to test for this as it is already a compile error.  Nobody can write that code and get it to compile, so why test for it.

As to your question: No, you cannot tell Eclipse to surpress a compiler error.

The fact that Eclipse let's you run this code at all is actually a feature of the Eclipse Compiler.  It will insert a special Exception at the spot of the compile error and continue compiling your classes.  If during execution of the code a part of the code is hit that couldn't be compiled, this exception is thrown instead.

This allows for fast turnovers when testing code, as you can run a part of your project (like a JUnit test) without having to fix all errors in a project first.

Comment: Makes perfect sense... I was overthinking the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @SierraBravo Or underthinking. Could it be that you didn't grasp exactly what it means to work with a strictly, statically typed language like Java?